# Django form validation no function call

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have the following problem.
I have the **forms.py** file:

```
@parsleyfy
class FilterWebsitesForm(forms.Form):
     domain = forms.RegexField(min_length=3, regex=re.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9-_., ]+$"), error_messages={'invalid': ("Only these characters are acceptable in a domain name: letters, numbers, hyphens, spaces, commas and dots.")}, required=False, label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'domain', 'class': 'text_search padding_both', 'id': 'domain_id'}))
```

**views.py**:

```
from myapp.forms import FilterWebsitesForm

def websites_display(request):
    limit = 100
    fwfForm = FilterWebsitesForm()
    start = time.clock()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fwfForm = FilterWebsitesForm(request.POST or None)
    
        if fwfForm.is_valid():
            queries = {}
        ...
```

**main_display.html**

```
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button_search').click(function() {
            $('#first').show();
            $('#records_list').block({ message: null });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the main_display.html file, the loader is displayed until the result is returned.
When a user enters the correct characters, the loader works fine. Disappears when the result is returned.

When a user enters the wrong characters into the form, the Regexfield displays the message, but also runs the javascript function, and that is not what I want because the loader runs forever.

The problem is when the validation error message is displayed, the websites_display function is not executed (breakpoint at limit = 100), that's why I can't check {% if form.errors %} to run the javascript function.

I can't find any information about this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your whole views.py function, but based on what you are reporting, I would start by looking at what happens when

```
if fwfForm.is_valid():
```

is False.

What you may need -- again, you didn't provide but I know I have made this error -- is something like:

```
def websites_display(request):
    limit = 100
    fwfForm = FilterWebsitesForm()
    start = time.clock()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fwfForm = FilterWebsitesForm(request.POST or None)

        if fwfForm.is_valid():
           queries = {}
            ... 
        else:
           context = {'form': fwfForm}
           return render(request, 'main_display.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi Terry,

The problem is that when a user enters an incorrect character, the message from regex forms.py is displayed:
"Only these characters are acceptable in a domain name: letters, numbers, hyphens, spaces, commas and dots.", but the function websites_display is not executed. I'm wondering why?
If it was executed I already have code to handle this.

The function websites_display is executed when the characters entered by the user are correct.

Comment: Can you update question to include the rest of your websites_display function?  The portion of your function that you include only shows what happens if FilterWebsitesForm() is valid and does not show what happens if it is not valid.  If it is sending the error message to your view, then it is running the websites_display function but is not executing the if fwf.is_valid() clause because the form is not valid.